# Bayesian linear regression - Defining hyperparameters

Tags: regression, self-study, bayesian

I am currently working on a linear regression task from a textbook and I have some questions. In the following you will find the task as well as some thoughts of mine to possible results.

Short description: A quadratic regression analysis shall be made for temperature data from France. The explained variable is given by:
[image: Quadratic regression]

The conjugate prior is:

[image: Conjugate prior]

a) In the first task I shall determine the prior hyperparameters to suitable values:

[image: hyperparameters]

I can think about the prior mean as a guess of the average temperature in France (lets assume 20°C). But I can not make a sense out of the other parameters. How do I define the prior precision as well as the degrees of freedom and what are they telling me? I know that $\sigma^2$ can be derived from the Inv-$\chi^2$ distribution but how do I estimate $s_0^2$?